# Stop timer when intent start

Tags: android, android-intent

I made a countdown timer, it is start in 10sec, and when the timer is in 5sec the intent will execute but the timer continue and then when the timer done another intent will execute... that's my problem.
all I want is when the timer is in 5 sec intent will execute and timer will stop and no other executing of intent.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
String timerStr;
int timerInt;
Intent intent;
Intent intent2;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    intent = new Intent(this, Main3Activity.class);
    intent2 = new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class);

    new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000){

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            Log.i("Seconds left", String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished / 1000));
            timerStr = String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished / 1000);

            progress = Integer.parseInt(timerStr);
            Log.i("Timer: ", String.valueOf(progress));
            if (progress == 5){
                startActivity(intent2);    
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            Log.i("Done!","Countdown finished!");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }.start();

}
```

How to stop timer when intent start?

Comment: what you want I am not getting .Is your onTick Method is not calling or It is calling after 10 sec.

Comment: it is calling in onCreate

Comment: @smoy14 Can you explain this " intent will execute and timer will stop and no other executing of intent. " further ?

Comment: I mean. when timer is in 5 sec. then startActivity(intent2). then i want my timer to stop. because when I am in Main2Activity the countdown timer still on ticking. so all  i want is to stop the onThick when I am already in Main2Activity.

Comment: See this link https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/activity/android-timertask-example/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need this.
Your onTick method should go like this :

```
@Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        Log.i("Seconds left", String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished / 1000));
        timerStr = String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished / 1000);

        progress = Integer.parseInt(timerStr);
        Log.i("Timer: ", String.valueOf(progress));
        if (progress == 5){
            startActivity(intent2);
            if(timer!=null){
            timer.cancel(); //stop the timer by call
}
```

Hope this helps !!

Comment: what about the timer.cancel?

Comment: to stop the timer

Comment: Dont forget to Initialize the Timer using Timer timer = new Timer();

Comment: Please accept this as the verified answer. I understood and than edited your code. I did not provided you with an alternate code. I stick to your code.

Comment: Glad I could help! :) Please accept this as verified answer. Please upvote my answer!

Answer (score 0):

Just do it like this. Store your `CountDownTimer` in a variable and then call `cancel()` on it when it reaches `5s`.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
String timerStr;
int timerInt;
Intent intent;
Intent intent2;
CountDownTimer countDownTimer;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    intent = new Intent(this, Main3Activity.class);
    intent2 = new Intent(this, Main2Activity.class);

    coutDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000){

        @Override
        public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
            Log.i("Seconds left", String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished / 1000));
            timerStr = String.valueOf(millisUntilFinished / 1000);

            progress = Integer.parseInt(timerStr);
            Log.i("Timer: ", String.valueOf(progress));
            if (progress == 5){
                startActivity(intent2);  
                countDownTimer.cancel();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFinish() {
            Log.i("Done!","Countdown finished!");
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }.start();

}
```

Comment: is it possible to cancel timer inside same timer object because in my my code outside from timer or second timer is stoping

Comment: @android_jain Yes it is.